# Titan: How to efficienlty get the maximum value of a Long property?

Tags: titan

So if I want to retrieve the vertex that has the maximum value of a Long property, I should run:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("type","myType").values("myProperty").max().next()
```

This is really slow as it has to load all vertices to find out the maximum value. Is there any way faster?

Any indexing would help? I believe composite indexes won't help but is there a way to do it using mixed index with ElasticSearch back end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Titan to create a Mixed Index on a numeric value will result in Elasticsearch indexing the property correctly. Kind of similarly to you, we want to know all our vertices ordered by a property `DEGREE` from max to min so we currently do the following for the property `DEGREE`:

```
TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open("titan-cassandra-es.properties");
TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();

PropertyKey degreeKey = management.makePropertyKey("DEGREE").dataType(Long.class).make();

management.buildIndex("byDegree", Vertex.class)
.addKey(degreeKey)
.buildMixedIndex("search");
```

We are currently having issues getting Titan to traverse this quickly (for some reason it can create the index but struggles to use it for certain queries) but we can query Elasticsearch directly:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/titan/byDegree/_search?size=80' -d '
{
    "sort" : [
        { "DEGREE" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ],
   "query" : {

   }
}
```

The answer is returned **extremely** quickly so for now we create the index with Titan but query elastic search directly.

**Short Answer:** Elasticsearch can do what is needed with numeric ranges very easily, the problem on our side at least seems to be getting Titan to use these indices fully. However the traversal you are trying to execute is simpler than ours (you just want the max) so you may not encounter these issues and you may just be able to stick with Titan traversals fully.

**Edit:**

I have recently confirmed that elasticsearch and titan can fulfill your needs (as it does mine). Just be wary of how you create your indices. Titan will be able to execute your query quickly as long as you create your Mixed index with the `Type` key being set to a `String` match not a `Text` Match.

Comment: thanks a lot. This is really good but too complex. Hopefully such addition would be added to Gremlin in future versions.

Comment: I made it sound more complex than it is because at the time of answering I was still studying up myself. The process from Titan's end is actually really simply. I would recommend giving Mixed Indices a try